# Input data using Scanner in Java

Tags: java

Can anyone one tell what this statement exactly does?

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in) ;
```

what is (input) a variable or an object.What is System.in?
Please someone tell me what is meaning of this whole statement

Comment: It creates a `Scanner` object which reads from the "standard" `InputStream` `System.in`

Answer (score 0):

```
input
```

is a variable, more precisely an instance object of the class

```
Scanner
```

when you do

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
```

you create a variable named input that is a Scanner instance and reads inputs from the standard console until you close it with

```
input.close();
```

note that you cannot reopen the instance if you close it, if you want to re-read inputs you have to recreate it with:

```
input = new Scanner(System.in);
```